# Overflow auto does not show all content

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

So I'm trying to make an hamburger menu, and when the button is clicked it comes from top since it's styled as `top: -100%` at the beginning.

It's working fine but when its height is bigger than window height, `overflow: auto` makes vertical scroll so i can get to the bottom of menu.

The problem is that i cant always get to the very bottom and i dont see the bery last item, because it depends on window height.

```css
.header__menu_mobile {
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color: #252525;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.header__menu_mobile .header__list {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    width: 100%;
}
.header__menu_mobile .header__list li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.header__menu_mobile .header__list li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #252525;
}
.header__menu_mobile.active {
    top: 63px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__menu_mobile">
 <div class="container">
  <ul class="header__list">
   <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 6</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 7</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 8</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="contacts">
   <a class="contact">Email</a>
   <a class="contact">Instagram</a>
   <a class="contact">Facebook</dav>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Meybe the problem is `top: 63px` while menu is active, but in this layout it has to be excactly like this. When i change it to `top: 0`, overflow auto shows me the last item on every window height.

So meybe these 63px is also taken away from the bottom of menu. But what should i do?

Comment: Can you please add HTML code Also

Comment: Replace `height: 100%;` with `height: calc(100% - 63px);` maybe?

Comment: @DavydMelnychenko I hope you don't mind but I took the freedom to edit your question so that your code could run in a live snippet. I kept everything as is except the fact I changed your scss to regular css so that it was going to work with no further processing. I think the issue is not the scss per se so I hope it won't be a problem.

Comment: FYI: Instead of manipulating the `top` property, you should rather use a `transform: translateY()`. That has better performance for animating/transitioning.

Comment: @CBroe yes, that's actually works. I was trying to do this but only with top property. Thank you a lot

Comment: @DiegoD thank you also for editing my question. You helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. The problem was solved when i changed `height: 100%` to `height: calc(100% - 63px);`. Thanks [@Cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) and [@DiegoD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221208/diego-d) for help